# childNode inside a div element

Tags: javascript

I'm learning the JavaScript right now and I'm writing functions to change the style of the each **paragraph tag** and the font-style tag **emphasis(em)** and **bold(b)** which is inside the **`<div>`** element.**Here is my program**.

```
<div id = "sampDiv2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <em>consectetur adipiscing</em> elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipiscing</b> elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
<em>Excepteur sint</em> occaecat cupidatat non proident, <b>sunt in culpa</b> qui 
officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<script>
var pElements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
pElements[1].style.backgroundColor = "#EFDECD";

document.childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = "#FAEBD7";

var sampDiv2 = document.getElementById('sampDiv2');

sampDiv2.childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF";
</script>
```

what I'm trying is to change the color of the `<p>` tags used inside the div element. But when I run the output, the console says **sampDiv2.childNodes[0].style is undefined**

Answer (score 3):

The **[`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)** includes text nodes also, so it's better to use **[`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)** instead which returns html elements.

```html
<div id="sampDiv2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <em>consectetur adipiscing</em> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipiscing</b> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    <em>Excepteur sint</em> occaecat cupidatat non proident, <b>sunt in culpa</b> qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<script>
  var pElements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  pElements[1].style.backgroundColor = "#EFDECD";

  document.body.children[1].style.backgroundColor = "#FAEBD7";

  var sampDiv2 = document.getElementById('sampDiv2');

  sampDiv2.children[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF";
</script>
```

Comment: @RSN : check docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with css.

```
<style>
p    {background-color:#EFDECD;}
em    {color: red;}
b    {color: darkblue;}
</style>
```

With this all `<p>` element will have that background colors, `em` elements will be red and bold elements will be dark blue. [Learn more about css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) to know more.

By the way, the code above works if put in the html file, but it's recommended to put in in a separate css file (with `<style>` removed) and use that css file in your html file.

If you want to easily select elements, you can do this with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
//Targets all descendendants of the element with id #sampDiv2 that are 'p' tags
$("#sampDiv2 p").css({"background-color": "#F0FFFF"});
```

You can also get those elements in pure javascript using [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
//nodes is an array with all the elements in it
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#sampDiv2 p");

//To change the first one, but then document.querySelector() would have been enough
nodes[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF";

//To change all
for (let node of nodes) {
    node.style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF";
}

//Alternative in case above is not yet supported:
nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    node.style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF";
});
```

---

Even then, I'd recommend changing the css class of your elements (with the class containing all the css info) rather than editing the style directly.

```
//jQuery way
$("#sampDiv2 p").addClass("abc");

//alternative
for (let node of document.querySelectorAll("#sampDiv2 p")) {
    node.classList.add("abc");
}
```

In the css:

```
.abc {
    /* css */
}
```

Or you can change the class of your div and do in the .css:

```
.myDivClass p {
   /* css for p tags under those div */
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to write the javascript function for the emphasis tag which is inside the children[0] which is the first p tag. I tried this, but the browser console is saying that this is wrong. 
sampDiv2.children[0].children[1].style.backgroundColor = "#BFAFB2";

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#sampDiv2 p:first-child em").forEach(function(element) { element.style.backgroundColor =  "magenta";})` or `$("#sampDiv2 p")[0].find("em").css("background-color", "gold")`.

Comment: this is working, can you please tell me how to write in the way like I asked in the question because Im following a video tutorial on this and its working for the person who is teaching but not for me.

Comment: TypeError: sampDiv2.children[0].children[1] is undefined but his statement was sampDiv2.childNode[0].childNode[1].style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF" for the first emphasis tag in the first paragraph in div element

Comment: indexes in arrays start with 0. `.children[1]` would be the *second* child.

Comment: childNode and children are different as PranavCBalan said. with childNode the em would be the second child as there is text before. With children just do: ampDiv2.children[0].children[0].style.backgroundColor = "#BFAFB2";. You have all the answers you want with mine + PranavCBalan's, so check out the links given and understand  our codes, what you're trying to do manually will never be done in production code the way you want to do it, it's just too tedious verbose and prone to massive errors if the html changes the least bit.

Comment: but it works for him, the guy who is teaching. Then who's that possible?

Comment: childNode can work, they just behave even more unpredictably than children. Follow the links in Pranav's answer, print all the nodes and you'll understand. Or ask for help from your teacher.

Comment: k, i will try something different. Good day!, thanks for ur patience guys